# MS Project - XML imported with wrong duration, Start and Finish dates

Tags: xml, import, ms-project

I have created a XML file to import to MS Project 2019 using Javascript.

The problems I have only on duration, start and finish dates. I don't understand why MS Project changes the values if on XML is correct. Bellow the XML with correct values and screenshot of the project imported with wrong values. What is the problem?

For example, on the XML, the task “configure port” is with this data:

```
<Name>Configure ports</Name>
<Duration>P2DT0H0M0S</Duration>
<Start>2019-01-14T00:00:00</Start>
<Finish>2019-01-16T00:00:00</Finish>
```

But the image show the xml I imported the MS Project converted it to:

```
duration: 0 days
start: 2019-01-14
finish: 2019-01-14
```

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aydiqp5gh301jrb/screen%20shot%202020-10-16%20at%2011.58.21.png?dl=0

XML File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yt89b7pagnagac2/launch%20saas%20product.xml?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem.

To work is required to add the field "RemainingDuration" to the tasks and change the format to hours from days to hours. Even microsoft doc to suppose to format duration like P2DT1H0M for 2 days 1 hour but the correct they support is only in days PT25H0M for 2 days and 1 hour.

Thank you!